# Moss over stone text?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

I have 3d text and I want to add moss on top of the text similarily like on this Terraria logo:[image]

I want the object to add moss particle system to follow the geometry of the top of the text (above red line). Maybe there is some way that I can make something like scaled cube put it on top of the text and simulate it so it would fall on the text acting like some kind of cloth and then stop the animation so it would have the geometry of text's top like this:[image]

Is it possible or do I have to sculpt it manualy?

Comment: also look at the Ivy add-on that is built in. You can use it to "grow" all sorts on your mesh with a fair bit of control. Google for tutorials.

Comment: Definitely helpful, but I need mesh on top of it.

Comment: you can do that with a simple cloth simulation, there are plenty tutorials on that topic